# Show the voting on specific posts over time

Tags: feature-request, voting, tracking

I would like to be able to see a per-post (question/answer) vote graph in order to see how posts' votes trend over time.

Something similar to the per-user reputation graph but for posts.

Answer (score 2):

Best you can achieve is such a thing:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/107357/timeline

This hidden feature of SE (it works globally, just replace `107357` with the post ID as seen in URL) reveals, among other things, how many upvotes and downvotes the question and each answer got, on daily basis.

You can't see it "zoomed" to exact time of voting, it's by design as the voting should remain anonymous meaning you can't know who voted on what.

Comment: OK so the data is there, all that's missing is a decent UI.

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Personally I don't think such UI will be implemented, it's not important enough. But no harm in asking!

Comment: @rene thanks for the edit but the problem is the post is deleted, not the split.

Answer (score 0):

1. This would make it easier to guess who voted which way (based on comments, post times, "last seen", etc. I don't think that it would benefit the community overall to have vote times be available.
2. Just being able to see how many up- and down- votes a post has, rather than its total score, is a [privilege that takes significant rep to earn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user). This provides more information so it would only ever make sense restricted to that reputation level or higher.