# Sparklines for voting history?

Tags: feature-request, design

Often while looking back over an old question, I am unsure of exactly when the up- and down-votes summarized were given.  It would be great to have a graphical summary, in the line of Tufte's [Sparklines](http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0001OR), right there on the page.

Sparklines could coexist with the numeric summary or could stand on their own when the vote was clicked for a second time.

[image: Without sparklines]

[image: With sparklines]

Comment: I don't get why you'd need/want that. Why does this matter to you?

Comment: Actually such a timeline would make most sense if it also shows when revisions (and possibly comments) were made - usually an extensive revision is what will turn a question from being down- to being upvoted.

Comment: You can use the question [timeline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/109459/timeline) for that I think.

Comment: This would be a great idea for a [UserScript](http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show the voting on specific posts over time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107357/show-the-voting-on-specific-posts-over-time)

Comment: @Chris, thanks for pointing out the other Q.  I definitely think it's related, but my question is specifically about Sparklines and therefore distinct.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good suggestion.  This distinguishes between questions or answers that were upvoted long ago, those that are upvoted on a continuing basis, and those that are most significant after some event (e.g. the posting of a better answer).  Other distinctions may arise, but these 3 are interesting enough.

I think that this is more relevant for answers than questions.  Suppose a question was posed in July 2010, 3 answers were given at that time, and then in July 2011 another answer was provided.  The first three answers may have accumulated a lot more votes due to their longevity, but the answer from 7/11 may be upvoted a lot more among the three during the time after its post.  This could well be due to a much better, cleaner answer.

Although SO doesn't seem to sort based on current "voting intensity", I believe the proposal is a graphical representation of this idea.